# Why is jQuery code working fine in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code to show popup("showing please wait message"). This code is working very well in Firefox,but not in Chrome or IE browser. Please check my code and tell me why it's not working.
Script Code.

```
function ShowStickerWindow() {
    if (_ajaxRequests.length < 1) {
        var width;
        var height;
        //calculating body width. handle IE 6
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
            var scrollWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.body.scrollWidth);
            var offsetWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.offsetWidth, document.body.offsetWidth);
            if (scrollWidth < offsetWidth) {
                width = $(window).width() + 'px';
            } else {
                width = scrollWidth + 'px';
            }
            // handle "good" browsers
        } else {
            width = $(document).width() + 'px';
        }
        //calculating body width. handle IE 6
        // handle IE 6
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
            var scrollHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);
            var offsetHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.offsetHeight, document.body.offsetHeight);
            if (scrollHeight < offsetHeight) {
                height = $(window).height() + 'px';
            } else {
                height = scrollHeight + 'px';

            }
            // handle "good" browsers
        } else {
            height = $(document).height() + 'px';
        }

        $('#' + _screenDiv).addClass('screen').css({
            'width': width,
            'height': height,
            'zIndex': 10000
        });
        $('#' + _screenDiv).show();
        var wnd = $(window),
            doc = $(document),
            pTop = doc.scrollTop(),
            pLeft = doc.scrollLeft();
        pLeft += (wnd.width() - 200) / 2;
        pTop += (wnd.height() - 200) / 2;
        //_processingDiv is the id of Popup
        $('#' + _processingDiv).css({
            'left': pLeft + 'px',
            'top': pTop + 'px',
            'zIndex': 10001
        }).show();
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
            $('select').each(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="divPopup" style="border: #cccccc 1px solid; background-color: #ffffff; padding: 30px; display: none; position: absolute; font-size: 14px;"
    runat="server">
    <div class="darkf" style="text-align: center">       
        <asp:Localize runat="server" ID="locPleaseWait" Text="Please wait..." meta:resourcekey="locPleaseWaitResource1"></asp:Localize>
    </div>
</div>
```

ShowStickerWindow();

Comment: Seems like jQuery version <1.9 otherwise you'll also not be able to run it in firefox because `$.browser` has been removed from _JQuery 1.9._

Comment: then please tell me the solution , its very urgent.

Comment: @user3810961 refer this link **http://www.sitepoint.com/fix-jquery-browser-function/**